# jQuery - tabs, use url to load ajax content

Tags: jquery, ajax, tabs

So my script looks like this

```
function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});

function Wczytaj(link, div_id, parametr1, parametr2, parametr3)
{
   $.ajax(link, { data: { par1: parametr1, par2: parametr2, par3: parametr3 },
   type: "post",
     success: function(data) {
       $('#'+div_id).fadeOut("medium", function(){
       $(this).append(data);
      $('#'+div_id).fadeIn("medium");
     });
  }
 });
}
```

```html
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#id1" onClick="Wczytaj('trouble2.php','id1','null','null','null');">My id 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#id2" onClick="Wczytaj('trouble2.php?action=lista','id2','null','null','null');">My id 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#id3" onClick="Wczytaj('troubl2.php?action=old','id3','null','null','null');">My id3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="id1"></div>
    <div id="id2"></div>
    <div id="id3"></div>
</div>
```

And it works without a problem, BUT I want to use also an URL address to load div content
for example, `http://myurl.com/page.php#id2` should load page with selected tabs with `id2` - it works, but div is empty because of `onClick` attribute. How to fix it?

I apologize for my english

Comment: What does the `Wczytaj` function do?

Comment: If you set the `href` of the `<a>` tag to a URL, jQuery UI will AJAX load the page into a tab for you.  http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax

Comment: @RocketHazmat , I've just updated my question. Function Wczytaj loads content to div.

Comment: You don't need that function, jQuery UI can AJAX load it for you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't need to use your own function to AJAX load into tabs, jQuery can do this for you.  Just set the `href` to the URL, and don't add the `<div>`s.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="trouble2.php">My id 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="trouble2.php?action=lista">My id 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="trouble2.php?action=old">My id3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery will make the tabs, and *automatically* load the page via AJAX.  See the docs here: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax

It will also make the `<div>` for you.  In the example, they are named `ui-tabs-X`, where `X` is the tab index.  So, `http://myurl.com/page.php#ui-tabs-2` should load the page with your 2nd tab open.

Check out jQuery's demo here: http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/tabs/ajax.html#ui-tabs-2

**EDIT**: If you want to run a function before or after the remote tabs are loaded, jQuery UI provides the [`tabsbeforeload`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-beforeLoad) and [`tabsload`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-load) events.

They can be bound when creating the tabs:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    beforeLoad: function(event, ui){
        alert('loading');
    },
    load: function(event, ui){
        alert('loaded');
    }
});
```

Or they can be bound afterwards:

```
$('#tabs').on('tabsbeforeload', function(event, ui){
    alert('loading');
});

$('#tabs').on('tabsload', function(event, ui){
    alert('loaded');
});
```

Comment: Ok, but with "my" function i have a 'loading' effect. (beforesend, and success). How to get this effect bu using just url?

Comment: jQuery UI also has these events, `tabsbeforeload` and `tabsload`.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hi , am using the href as shown in the answer above, but only the href set to #id of div in the page loads, the rest set to external php do not load. Please help here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210586/jquery-ui-tabs-with-ajax-content-hrefs-not-working)

Comment: Is there any way to provide ID for those ajax pages ?

Comment: @hsuk: What do you mean?  What are you asking?

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat: As you are saying for ajax pages, `<div>` is made and ID is provided as ui-tabs-X, I am asking if this ID can be assigned by us ourselves ?

Comment: @hsuk: Unfortunately, I don't think so.

Comment: @RocketHazmat : I found its possible, if we provide a title attribute on anchor tab, the same value provided on title will be id of the div created for remote tabs

Comment: @hsuk: Cool!  Didn't realize you could do that :-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat : yeah, realization comes over effort and research :)

Comment: @hsuk: And experimentation :-D

Comment: Again its not working for jQuery UI 1.10, seems like its made for jQuery 1.8 only

Comment: @hsuk It seems that in jQuery UI 1.10 you set the id of the panel using the `aria-controls` attribute of the `<li>`

https://www.flynsarmy.com/2015/05/specify-jquery-ui-ajax-tabs-panel-element/

Comment: @RocketHazmat, topic is fairly old but have you come across a solution to opening a tabs href link when a user selects to open it in a new tab/window, either through a right click and select new tab or a click on the mouse wheel. The problem is that when this is done the new window loads the links content and you end up with a bare page. If this is done I need the action to load the whole page at the new window loaded at the tab this action was carried out on, if you get me??

Answer (score 1):

Reset the href url before load the tab ajax content in Jquery:

```
$( "#pending_recs" ).tabs({
    beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
        var filter_url = get_url();
        var url_str = site_url+'/admin/pending_recs/'+filter_url+"/0";

        $("#pending_recs .ui-tabs-nav .ui-state-active a").attr('href',url_str);

        ui.panel.html('<div class="loading">Loading...</div>');

        ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
            ui.panel.html('<div align="center"><p>Unable to load the content, Please <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return load_contents();">Click here to Reload</a>.</p></div>');
        });
    }
    ,load:function( event, ui ) { /* After page load*/  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just set the `href` attribute of each of the tab links to the ajax URL you are supposed to load it should work.

If you don't want to do that, then get rid of the `onClick` attributes.  The problem is that when the page loads the trigger for selecting a particular tab such as `#id2` happens before the click elements are bound.  You need to bind the click handlers before that and call the corresponding one when the tab in question is selected by the fragment.